# fab Floating button is not working in Fragment page..... its get error "Not Responding" when i click allotment in sidebar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.allotment, container, false);

    final WebView webView = (WebView) myView.findViewById(R.id.webViewAllotment);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.rwdbihar.in/latestUpdate.aspx");
    getActivity().setTitle("Allotment");
    FloatingActionButton myFab = (FloatingActionButton) myView.findViewById(R.id.fab);
    myFab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            webView.loadUrl("http://www.rwdbihar.in/latestUpdate.aspx");
        }
    });
   return myView;
```

Comment: post error logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this it works for me :-

```
   final WebView webView = (WebView) myView.findViewById(R.id.webViewAllotment);  
                             webView.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.rwdbihar.in/latestUpdate.aspx");
    webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);

private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
  return true;
    }
}
```